# Android - how to use parse xml using Retrofit SimpleXML?

Tags: android, api, xml-parsing, retrofit, rx-android

I just started working with Retrofit. I am working on a project that uses SimpleXML. I am attempting to fetch XML from the site http://www.supermarketapi.com but am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for rx.Observable<com.crosser.brian.shakennotstirred.Models.StoreResultModel> for method SupermarketProvider.getStoreSearchResults
```

The xml I am trying to fetch looks like:
[http://www.supermarketapi.com/api.asmx/StoresByZip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf889.png)

Below I have provided excerpts from my project. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

StoreResultModel File:

```
public class StoreResultModel {

  @Root(name = "ArrayOfStore")
  ArrayList<StoreModel> searchStoresResults;

  public ArrayList<StoreModel> getSearchStoresResults(){
      return searchStoresResults;
  } 
}
```

StoreModel File:

```
@Root(name = "Store")
public class StoreModel {

    @Element(name ="Storename")
    public String storename;

    @Element(name ="Address")
    public String address;

    @Element(name ="City")
    public String city;

    @Element(name ="State")
    public String state;

    @Element(name ="Zip")
    public String zip;

    @Element(name ="Phone")
    public String phone;

    @Element(name ="StoreId")
    public int storeId;



    public int getStoreId() {
        return storeId;
    }

    public String getStorename(){
        return storename;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }

    public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }

    public String getState(){ return state; }

    public String getZip() { return zip; }

    public String getPhone() { return phone; }

    public void setStoreId(int storeID) { this.storeId = storeId; }

    public void setStorename(String storename) { this.storename = storename; }

    public void setAddress(String address) { this.address = address; }

    public void setCity(String city) { this.city = city; }

    public void setState(String state) { this.state = state; }

    public void setZip(String zip) { this.zip = zip; }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }


}
```

SuperMarketAPIClient File:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppDefines.SUPERMARKET_API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

My API call:

```
SupermarketAPIClient.getSupermarketProvider()
                    .getStoreSearchResults(AppDefines.SUPERMARKET_API_KEY, ZipCode)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Subscriber<StoreResultModel>() {
```

SupermarketProvider File:

```
@GET("/api.asmx/StoresByZip")
Observable<StoreResultModel> getStoreSearchResults(@Query("APIKEY") String key,
                                                    @Query("ZipCode") String zip);
```

AppDefines File:

```
public static final String SUPERMARKET_API_URL = "http://www.SupermarketAPI.com";
public static final String SUPERMARKET_API_KEY = "**********";
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `build.gradle` (under `dependencies`):

```
compile "com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:$project.retrofitVersion"
```

(replace `$project.retrofitVersion` with the version you are using, presumably 2.0.0-beta1 or 2.0.0-beta2).

And add this line to you `Retrofit.Builder`:

```
.addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
```

If I am not mistaken your error has nothing to do with XML but with the fact that Retrofit 2 now needs the RxJava adapter to be able to return `Observable`s instead of `Call`s.

Comment: I have that dependency already in my build.grade @david.mihola

Comment: So how about you also add the line to your `Retrofit.Builder`?

Comment: Added the line and it helped! Thank you! Now I'm getting the error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'Store' does not have a match in class ...Models.StoreResultModel at line 3 @david.mihola

Comment: Great, you're welcome! That's a wholly different problem - this one is really only related to simplexml and not Retrofit in particular. I would recommend opening a new question for that. But my guess is that the `@Root` line in `StoreResultModel` should be in front of the class name - just like in `StoreModel`.